# GWT RPC call doesn't rollback transaction after runtime exception

Tags: java, gwt, transactions, rpc, gwt-rpc

I yet don't know GWT such deep as I want. So I'd want to ask someone who know GWT well.

I have problem with rollback transaction in GWT 2.3. Say, GWT makes RPC call of service, and there will be thrown `NullPointerException`. As far as I am seeing now, implementation of `doUnexpectedFailure` in the class `AbstractRemoteServiceServlet` doesn't rethrow any exception - it just resets response and logging exception. Also, documentation for that method says that I should override this method to handle unexpected exception in GWT. Did anybody deal with this problem? Did anybody override `doUnexpectedFailure`? How could I correct do this?

Thanks for any comment in advance and sorry for my English!

Comment: transaction you mean is the JPA transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the manual:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html

Say, you have a service in your client:

```
private MyServiceAsync service= GWT.create(MyService.class);
```

Now, the service is created

This is the way a call in your client will look like:

```
// Set up the callback object.
AsyncCallback<MyModel> myCallback = new AsyncCallback<MyModel>() {
  public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    try {
      throw caught;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
       // TODO: Handle your NPE 
    }
  }

  public void onSuccess(MyModelresult) {
    // everything is ok
  }
};
// Make the call to the stock price service.
service.doSomethingOnTheServer(callback);
```

In the onFailure method you can handle your NPE on the client side. The `doUnexpectedFailure`-method is called, because your NPE is not a checked exception.

Comment: named exception - did you mean checked exception?

Comment: @ElHoss why do you have a try/catch in the `onFailure` method? You can do `if (caught instanceof NullPointerException) { //Handle NPE }`

Comment: Any exception, that is not catched in the try/catch block will be caught by an UncaughtExceptionHandler - defined f. e. in your EntryPoint. For example, if your service call throws an NotAuthorizedException, this exception will be handle by a gloabl exception handler. Of course you can also use an if statement and throw the exception in the else case. This will be the same.